# React kept show broken image(s)

Tags: reactjs, image

I have

Card.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Card(props) {
    console.log(props)
    return (
        <div className="card">
            <img src={props.imageUrl} alt={props.title} />
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Card
```

CardList.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Card from './Card'
import './CardList.css'

function CardList() {
    const [cardsData, setCardsData] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchCardsData() {
            const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/folders')
            const data = await response.json()
            setCardsData(data)
        }
        fetchCardsData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="card-list">
            {cardsData.map((card) => (
                <Card key={card.id} imageUrl={card.imageUrl} title={card.title} />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardList
```

__

I kept seeing broken images

[image]

I inspect, it looked correct

[image]

If I copy that path out paste into Chrome, I see image loaded perfectly

[image]

Why react show diff result ?

Comment: In the browser's debugging tools, on the network tab, are requests made for the images?  Do they match the URL you expect?  What is the server's response?  The last image shown doesn't appear to be using a URL at all and is just loading an image file from the file system.  The file(s) may *exist* on the file system, but how have you confirmed whether the web server is finding them based on any specific URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected because you're trying to display images on the local filesystem, which is not permitted by a browser for security reasons.

When you open the image directly in the browser, as in your screenshot you are simply using the browser to view an image without any web page, which is why it works.

You can serve the images in your public directory or have another web server host them, or bundle them with the React app.